# Custom TPL Block: how to test Consume, Release, Reserve

Tags: c#, nunit, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Suppose I want to create a custom `ISourceBlock<T>`. From the [MSDN sliding window example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-dataflow-block-type), I could begin the construction of my custom block like so:

```
public sealed class SomeCustomBlock<T> : ISourceBlock<T>
{
    private readonly int _somePrivateMember = 0;
    private readonly ISourceBlock<T> _source = new BufferBlock<T>();

    public void Complete() => _source.Complete();
    public void Fault(Exception exception) => _source.Fault(exception);
    public Task Completion => _source.Completion;
    
    public T? ConsumeMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<T> target, out bool messageConsumed)
    {
        return _source.ConsumeMessage(messageHeader, target, out messageConsumed);
    }

    public IDisposable LinkTo(ITargetBlock<T> target, DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions)
    {
        return _source.LinkTo(target, linkOptions);
    }

    public void ReleaseReservation(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<T> target)
    {
        _source.ReleaseReservation(messageHeader, target);
    }

    public bool ReserveMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<T> target)
    {
        return _source.ReserveMessage(messageHeader, target);
    }
}
```

The trouble is, since the implementation of the `ISourceBlock<T>` interface is forwarded to my private `_source` field, linked blocks will not call `SomeCustomBlock`'s implementation of `ConsumeMessage`, `ReleaseReservation`, and `ReserveMessage` methods directly: they'll call the `_source`'s, aka `BufferBlock<T>`'s implementation. In fact, I have had a heck of a time trying to get the `SomeCustomBlock`'s implementation of these methods to be called at all; any target that calls these methods will communicate with `_source` since that is the block they directly link with.

My questions:

1. How can I write unit tests to verify that I've been a good developer and have not broken `SomeCustomBlock`'s implementation of the `ConsumeMessage`, `ReleaseReservation`, and `ReserveMessage` methods? I work a lot with NUnit, but I'm not opposed to another testing framework if it's required.
2. Is there a better way to create a custom TPL block that I can more easily test fully, assuming I need to derive directly from `ISourceBlock<T>` rather than using the [Encapsulate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.encapsulate?view=net-7.0) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You discovered a major disadvantage of the TPL Dataflow library: extending it is a pain. The interaction between the linked dataflow blocks is so convoluted that even Microsoft can't get it right, and there are still [known bugs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31513) that are so hard to fix that have not been fixed, after being reported for years.

When you link the `_source` to the `target` in the `SomeCustomBlock<T>.LinkTo` method, the `_source` will start sending messages to the `target` directly, by invoking the `target`'s `ConsumeMessage` method. Your `SomeCustomBlock<T>` class alone has no way of intercepting this communication between `_source` and `target`. What you can do is to write a  `ITargetBlock<T>` implementation that will serve as a middle man between the `_source` and the `target`, whose activity you'll be able to intercept:

```
private class LinkedTargetProxy : ITargetBlock<T>
{
    private readonly ITargetBlock<T> _realTarget;
    private readonly SomeCustomBlock<T> _realSource;

    public LinkedTargetProxy(ITargetBlock<T> realTarget, SomeCustomBlock<T> realSource)
    {
        _realTarget = realTarget;
        _realSource = realSource;
    }
    //...
}

public IDisposable LinkTo(ITargetBlock<T> target, DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions)
{
    LinkedTargetProxy targetProxy = new(target, this);
    return _source.LinkTo(targetProxy, linkOptions);
}
```

You can find examples of using this technique in these answers:

- [Prevent BroadcastBlock from sending buffered message on LinkTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63160739/prevent-broadcastblock-from-sending-buffered-message-on-linkto/63172147#63172147)
- [How can I gain access input queue of ActionBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769746/how-can-i-gain-access-input-queue-of-actionblock/63616861#63616861)
- [Batching on duration or threshold using TPL Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633346/batching-on-duration-or-threshold-using-tpl-dataflow/69148085#69148085)